# Changing position of origin (0,0) and all relative points

Tags: java, math, libgdx

According to LibGDX's coordinate system, (0, 0) is the bottom left corner. I would like to be able to specify where (0, 0) is in world coordinates.

[image: example]

In the picture, the point `(200, 200)` is relative to the zero in the bottom left corner. How can I (mathematically or built-in function) change the coordinates to be relative to the other zero?

The I have the coordinates of the second zero relative to the zero in the bottom left corner, and for this purpose let's set it to `(800, 500)`

Comment: do you know the position of the new zero in relation to the old zero?

Comment: yes, I do, I will modify my post to add this fact @TNTFreaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply find the distance between (200, 200) and (800, 500) before you set the new zero.

> x distance: x1 - x2
>
> y distance: y1 - y2
>
> xDist = 200 - 800 = -600
>
> yDist = 200 - 500 = -300

So your new point in relation to the new zero is (-600, -300).

Comment: No problem!! @Rohan

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your question, but you should just be able to add the new "0" to your coordinates.

As an example, to modify the point (200, 200) to be relative to (800, 500) you would change it to (1000, 700), or (200 + 800, 200 + 500).

Comment: The point is low and to the left of the new zero so it doesn't make sense for your point to be further up and to the right.

Comment: Arn't you just shifting both point though? The original center was to the bottom left, and the point was up and to the right of it. Wouldn't moving the center up and to the right also move the point up and to the right?

Comment: @TNTFreaks Or do libGDX's coordinates just not go positive left to right and down to up?

Comment: He is only moving the new zero, the other point remains in the same position. He wants the point's coordinates in relation to the new zero. @the4naves

Comment: @TNTFreak Ah I see, I did completely misunderstand the question then :). I thought he wanted to move the point so it would be the same relatively to the new center. Thanks